# Is there an easy way to retrieve the start time stamp from TimeSpan

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timespan

What is the difference between the `TimeSpan` private field `startTimeStamp` and the `DateTime.Ticks` property? Is there an easy way to retrieve the `startTimeStamp` (without using reflection) ?

[image]

Comment: If you don't know the difference why do you feel you need to access a private value ?

Comment: What does `DateTime.Ticks` have to do with the question?

Comment: `startTimeStamp` is not `TimeSpan` field. It's from **`StopWatch`**!

Comment: I gotta go with @MarcinJuraszek, what in the world are you asking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`startTimeStamp` is a long, it's not a `TimeSpan` and it's not necessarily `DateTime.Ticks`.

It will be the time the `StopWatch` was started, which will be the time based on a high performance counter, or `DateTime.Ticks` if no high performance counter is available.

You can get the current value for what `startTimeStamp` is generated from by calling `Stopwatch.GetTimeStamp()` static method.

The `startTimeStamp` is not directly exposed but you can calculate it by calling

```
Stopwatch.GetTimeStamp() - stopwatch.GetRawElapsedTicks()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the source of the method used to initialize that field:

```
    public static long GetTimestamp() {
        if(IsHighResolution) { 
            long timestamp = 0;
            SafeNativeMethods.QueryPerformanceCounter(out timestamp);
            return timestamp;
        } 
        else {
            return DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks; 
        } 
    }

    [DllImport(ExternDll.Kernel32)]
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
    public static extern bool QueryPerformanceCounter(out long value);
```

Since this method is `public`, you can also call it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can merely estimate the start time stamp. All you have to do is to call GetTimeStamp() just after starting StopWatch.

```
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();
long ts = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
```

[image]

and

> ts => 62583777603